# Magento 2, how to change the the word `IN STOCK` in product description?

Tags: product, magento2.2

Using `Magento 2.2`, `Front-end`, `Product-Calalog`. I want to rename the word `IN STOCK` to other word.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Method 1:**

If you want to change this text only for product details page and for that section which you mentioned then you need to copy the following file to your theme:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

You theme file location will be like below:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

And update the text.

**Method 2:**

Create one en_US.csv on your theme like below:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/i18n/en_US.csv

And add the translation text like "In stock","Salable"

Answer (score 4):

You can translate **"IN STOCK"** to **"Your Text"** by below translation file

Add **"IN STOCK","Your Text"** to below file

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Run below commands to check text changes

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: How to hide the word 'IN STOCK'?

Answer (score 4):

- Override
  **`<magento_root>/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/i18n/en_US.csv`** in
  **/app/design/frontend** folder and open the en_US.csv file.
- Find the text you want to translate and change the translation.
- If the text which you want to translate does not exist in the file, then write in the following format:

.

```
"text to translate","translated text"
```

For example, in your case write:

```
"In stock","Salable"
```

- Refresh the Magento's cache and check the frontend.